# Regex - Extract digits from a url

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this url:

http://example.com/things/stuff/532453?morethings&stuff=things&ver=1

I need just that number in the middle there. Closest I got was

(\d*)?\?

but this includes the question mark. Basiclly all numbers that come before the ? all the way to the slash so the ouput is 532453.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following regex `(?!\/)\d+(?=\?)`:

```
url = "http://example.com/things/stuff/532453?morethings&stuff=things"
url.match(/(?!\/)\d+(?=\?)/) # outputs 532453
```

This regex will attempt to match any series of digits only after a `/` and before `?` by using [negative/positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) without returning the `/` or `?` as part of the match.

A quick test within developer tools:

```
# create a list of example urls to test against (only one should match regex)
urls = ["http://example.com/things/stuff/532453?morethings&stuff=things", 
        "http://example.com/things/stuff?morethings&stuff=things",        
        "http://example.com/things/stuff/123a?morethings&stuff=things"]

urls.forEach(function(value) {
                 console.log(value.match(/(?!\/)\d+(?=\?)/)); 
             })

# returns the following:
["532453"]
null
null
```

Comment: @AnthonyForloney This lookaround thingy is awesome.

Comment: @vjdhama It is an incredibly useful feature that I feel plays a huge role in increasing the accuracy of regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Just use this:

```
([\d]+)
```

You can check this link out: https://regex101.com/r/hR2eY7/1

if you use javascript:

```
/([\d]+)/g
```

Comment: This will grab any other numbers in the url as well (notice the 1 at the end) I just need the ones between the / and the ?

Comment: @MattCoady You just add Negative lookahead (?!\/) and positive lookahead (?=\?) to ensure that your string is between / and ?. This is: (?!\/)[\d]+(?=\?)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
url = "http://example.com/things/stuff/532453?morethings&stuff=things"
number  = url.match(/(\d+)\?/g)[0].slice(0,-1)
```

Though the approach is slightly naive, it works. It grabs numbers with ? at the end then removes the `?` from the end using `slice`.

Comment: Hrmm... I should have given a better example. This will grab any other numbers in the url as well. I've updated the example. I just need the ones between the / and the ?

Comment: If his link contains some mroe digits in the `things` parts, then this will give a bad result

Comment: I noticed. Trying a different regex.